# Timeago giving me wrong amount of time

Tags: php, jquery, timeago

I'm trying to use timeago to display how long ago an action was done on my website.

I'm using an ajax request to add rows to a table, and then once all the rows are added, I'm activating the timeago again. I have a function called `fill_table()` which gathers some row data from a php script and then loops through the data adding rows to the table.

```
function fill_table() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success : function(data) { 
            var table = $('#table_body');
            table.empty();
            $.each(data, function( index, value ) {

                var date = new Date(new Date(value.last_updates).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Chicago"})).toISOString();

                var elem = '\
                    <tr>\
                        <td><a target="_blank" href="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + '</a></td>\
                        <td>' + value.market_value + '</td>\
                        <td>' + value.lowest_cost + '</td>\
                        <td>' + value.biggest_md_format + '</td>\
                        <td><time class="timeago" datetime="' + date + '"></time></td>\
                    </tr>\
                ';
                table.append(elem);
            });
            $("time.timeago").timeago();                
        },
        error : function(request,error)
        {
            console.log("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
}
```

Now, for some reason this is telling me "6 hours ago" for timestamps that should only be 8-12 minutes old at the most.

As you can see in the code, I've declared `date` using some crazy toLocaleString thing just to make sure it was the right timezone, I also already set the PHP header in my controller

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
```

Inspecting the timeago element gives me this

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2019-03-03T12:56:28.000Z">about 6 hours ago</time>
```

Which the datetime is correct, 12:56 AM CST (America/Chcago), but that is only about 10 minutes ago.

So I'm at a loss, I've tried fixing timezone issues with no luck and don't know what else to do.

How can I make timeago read the correct amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That datetime is *not* correct. That `Z` at the end designates it as UTC time zone, not your local time zone. So timeago correctly gives you a difference of multiple hours with that time in UTC.

Check your inputs and that conversion logic in JS.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using PHP to convert the time to ISO 8601 instead of Javascript and it's working now.